# debian 9.3 can't recover from suspend to ram

Tags: suspend, debian-stretch

I'm using Debian 9.3(stretch), linux kernel: 4.9.0-4-amd64, architecture: x86-64.

I tried recover my computer after the system had been suspended to ram, though it was clear that the system started to run(the fans started to work) but my screen was just black.

I also tried recover my computer after it had been suspended to disk, it worked well.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: I now use `s2disk` and write images to swap file now. It has been months and it has never failed.